# HtmlAgilityPack download webpage which loaded asynchronously by javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

i am using HtmlAgilityPack and trying to load some webpages. some webpages are javascript based and loads asynchoronously. is there any way to load web page after x seconds or after making sure page is completely loaded

Answer (score 0):

Html Agility Pack is not mimicking the client side calls to dynamically load content into the DOM. It is a headless scraper that is downloading the static page given by the server; if you want that content, you will have to mimic the calls made by the client browser. If you do not want to try to emulate the calls a browser would make, instead of using a headless scraper, you can use something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to do this for you, the down side being, the browser will be opened on the host machine.